# Connect Jmeter(windows) with VM (Linux)

Tags: linux, jmeter, virtual-machine, mqtt

I have Jmeter in local windows & application is running in  VM Linux.

Note: JMeter is not available in VM machine.

I need to establish connection to VM machine & thereby publish the data in MQTT broker in VM machine.

for VM connection, I have done below changes:

1. jmeter.properties: I have included:

   remote_hosts=XX.XX.XXX.XX:XX
2. user.properties, i have included:

   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true

And when i perform remote run, i could see the error:

"non-jrmp server at remote endpoint"

Am not sure, do I miss any points.

Comment: Just treat the VM as you would any other network connected machine.

Comment: You haven't actually explained what is wrong here or exactly how you've configured jmeter.

Comment: I have received : java.net.connectexception connection refused connect.  Do i need to install/ run JMeter in VM machine also ? somewhere its been defined to mention the port number of VM machine to avoid connection issue ? if so, where to define the port number in jmeter.properties file ?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61840117/edit) the question to add a LOT more detail about what you have configured where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand the concept of [Distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), defining `remote_hosts` property is needed when you need to connect JMeter to another JMeter so 2 (or more) JMeter instances would act as a single load generator, people normally do it when single JMeter cannot generate the required load because machine is not powerful enough.

If you have JMeter installed on your Windows machine and MQTT broker is running on Linux machine just install **MQTT Protocol Support** plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]

once done you will have `MQTT Connect` sampler where you will be able to configure your Linux machine IP address and port in order to establish connection with it:

[image]

More information: [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide)